# Загрузка аватарок на сервер

Tags: php

Оцените, пожалуйста (обзор кода).

```
<?php
//Если форма отправлена
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
//Массив ошибок
$error = array();
//Директория для загрузки картинок
$dir = 'upload';
//Имя файла
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
//Временная папка
$tmp  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
//Допустимые расширения
$ext = array('jpg','jpeg','gif', 'png', 'bmp');
//Расширение загружаемого файла
$ext2 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
//Новое имя файла
$new_name = time().'_'.rand(0, 1000).'.'.$ext2;
//Смотрим, есть ли ошибки во время загрузки
if($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)
{
    //Проверяем допустимость расширения загружаемого файла
    if(in_array($ext2, $ext))
    {   
        //Проверяем, картинку ли загрузил пользователь
        if($imginfo = getimagesize($tmp))
        {
            //Проверяем ширину и высоту загружаемого файла
            if($imginfo[0] < 100 and $imginfo[1] < 100)
            {
                //Если нету директории для загрузки картинок, создаем на лету
                if(!is_dir($dir)) mkdir($dir, 0777);
                //Перемещаем картинку в нужную папку
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $dir.'/'.$new_name))
                    $error[] = 'ФАЙЛ УСПЕШНО ЗАГРУЖЕН';
                else
                    $error[] = 'Ошибка: Не удалось загрузить файл';
            }
            else        
                $error[] = 'Ошибка: ширина и высота файла не могут быть больше 100 пикселей';
        }
        else
            $error[] = 'Ошибка: вы загружаете не картинку';
    }
    else
        $error[] = 'Ошибка: неверный формат файла';
}
else
{
    //Формируем ошибка
    switch($_FILES['file']['error'])
    {
        case 3:
            $error[] = 'Ошибка: Файл загружен частично';
            break;
        case 4:
            $error[] = 'Ошибка: Вы не выбрали файл';
            break;
    }
}

//Выводим ошибки
if(count($error) > 0)
{
    foreach($error as $err)
        echo '<p>'.$err.'</p>';
}

}
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Загрузить" />
</form>
```

Comment: заценил. что дальше :)

Comment: Прокомментировать вариант мой код?

Comment: ну подобная тема была, причем в таком же оформлении, собственно ничего не изменилось, есть с чем сравнивать. Велосипед? Быть может имело место копипаста.

Comment: нет, я не люблю копировать) ну по 5-ти бальной шкале оцени работоспособность и защиту скрипта

Comment: Каждый делает по своему, по-этому я не возьмусь ставить оценку ибо сделал бы по другому :)

Как говорили в студжизни, "3 гос оценка" :)

>$ext = array('jpg','jpeg','gif', 'png', 'bmp');
>//Расширение загружаемого файла
>$ext2 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

про это я уже писал, что не гуд, я могу и php загрузить ;)

Comment: а ты попробуй загрузить формат php, не получится

Comment: Ну постарался - молодец. Только проверка 

    if(in_array($ext2, $ext))

Лишняя явно. Проверяйте расширение которое возвращает функция `getimagesize()`.

Comment: не лишняя, проверки никогда не бывают лишними. самое главное - что данный скрипт безопасен, не пропустит ничего, кроме действительно изображений

Comment: ты на phpforum.ru запостил, теперь сюда :) По коду могу сказать что довольно плохо, я могу просто переименовать .php файл в картинку, и загрузить шелл, и через 5 минут я получу доступ к базе и ко всем скриптам, так что беги переписывать

Comment: кто тебе сказал что я не смогу загрузить изображения! тебе на phpforum сказали, и тут говорят! а ты не слушаешь, выложи свой код и дай ссылку, и смотри как ляжет твой сайт :)

Comment: Вы уверены в своих словах?

Comment: @vinnie лишняя.

Comment: Я так делал. Если бы был не уверен не говорил бы.

Answer (score 3):

Имхо, большая часть кода бесполезна. В большинстве случаев достаточно сделать что-то вроде:

```
try {
    $image = new Imagick($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $image->scaleImage(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, true);
    $image->writeImage('image.jpg');
    // картинка корректно загружена
} catch (ImagickException $ex) {
    // разбор ошибки
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для новичка - самое то. Главное понять принцип, а потом уже делать глобально! =)